# sqlite3 multiple inserts really slow

Tags: sqlite

I have build a file archiver in Windows which uses sqlite3 to store files and takes advantage of multicore techniques to complete the archive faster.

I am trying a backup of 100.000 files now and insertion is slow.

When I comment the line which inserts, the app uses 100% CPU which is normal. With the insertion line on, it rarely gets above 25%.

As the archiving progresses, insertion gets more and more slow, processing a few files/second with a cpu usage of 11%. No disk usage is shown, so the bottleneck can't be the disk.

I 've:

```
PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY
PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF
```

and the entire insertion is within a transaction.

After further analysis it seems that SQLite's problem is to bind the blob64 (if I pass 0, it seems to be fine).

Why SQLite would have a problem inserting a raw blob of data into the archive?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is my answer relevant?  I'm beginning to think more and more that it isn't.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to see the actual code!!!  We're very much shooting in the dark here.

Comment: I would urge you to reconsider your approach. `sqlite` does not run as a continuous daemon process, it restarts for every single request. It is a poor fit for backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer may lie here:

https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Because it says there that:

> The default mode is serialized.

which might explain your observations.

According to that document, you can either configure this at compile time (which I would most definitely not myself do) or via:

```
sqlite3_config (SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD);
```

Just how stratospherically it then performs I wouldn't know.